# Parse groups from regex string?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

If I have the following regex strings:

```
String one = "\"/^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(avi|bmp)$)([^.]+$)/i\"";
String two = "\"/^.*\\.(txt)$/i"";
```

Assuming I just want to parse the file extensions out of the strings, for example, I'd like:

```
List<String> fileExtensionsOne = getFileExtensionsFromRegex(one); // Returns ("avi",bmp")
List<String> fileExtensionsTwo = getFileExtensionsFromRegex(two); // Returns ("txt")
```

What's the best way to implement `getFileExtensionsFromRegex`? Is it possible to convert the string to Java Regex objects and grab the groups out of them? e.g. without applying the pattern to some input text?

Edit, I think I can rely on the regex patterns staying fairly consistent, either this:

```
'/^.*\\.(' + _map(extensions, 'text').join('|') + ')$/i'
```

or this:

```
'/^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(' + _map(extensions, 'text').join('|') + ')$)([^.]+$)/i'
```

Comment: How much of these regex patterns is constant? Is it always `"\"/^.*\\.(ext)$/i""` for the single-extension case, and `"\"/^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(ext1|ext2)$)([^.]+$)/i\""` for the two-extensions case, and similar for more than two extensions? I'm sure one can come up with lots of different regex patterns all doing the same file extension matching. And you surely don't want to write a full-fledged regex analyzer (unless you got a few years of spare time).

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Added some more info to the question - I think the patterns will stay consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is mainly to create a regex that analyzes the regex, something like

```
.*\(([a-z0-9\|]+)\).*
```

(Disclaimer: haven't checked it for correct regex syntax)

This looks for a group inside the regex, beginning with an opening paren `\(`, then containing any number of letters, digits and pipes `[a-z0-9\|]+` (assuming that file extensions allow for exactly these characters), followed by the closing paren `\)` and returns the content between the parens as `group(1)`. The group-returning is what the extra parens just inside the `\(` and `\)` pair are meant for.

In the first example, this should give `avi|bmp`, and in the second one `txt`.

Then, do a `split("\|")` on the `group(1)` result, and you get the individual extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need:

```java
public static List<String> getFileExtensionsFromRegex(String s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(("[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}"));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your logic could start with comparing each caracter is it letter by ASCII. Here is a quick ASCII characters reference:

```
{
"31": "",      "32": " ",     "33": "!",     "34": "\"",    "35": 
"#",    
"36": "$",     "37": "%",     "38": "&",     "39": "'",     "40": 
"(",    
"41": ")",     "42": "*",     "43": "+",     "44": ",",     "45": 
 "-",    
"46": ".",     "47": "/",     "48": "0",     "49": "1",     "50": 
"2",    
"51": "3",     "52": "4",     "53": "5",     "54": "6",     "55": 
"7",    
"56": "8",     "57": "9",     "58": ":",     "59": ";",     "60": 
"<",    
"61": "=",     "62": ">",     "63": "?",     "64": "@",     "65": 
"A",    
"66": "B",     "67": "C",     "68": "D",     "69": "E",     "70": 
"F",    
"71": "G",     "72": "H",     "73": "I",     "74": "J",     "75":
```

"K",
"76": "L",     "77": "M",     "78": "N",     "79": "O",     "80":
"P",
"81": "Q",     "82": "R",     "83": "S",     "84": "T",     "85":
"U",
"86": "V",     "87": "W",     "88": "X",     "89": "Y",     "90":
"Z",
"91": "[",     "92": "\",    "93": "]",     "94": "^",     "95":
"_",
"96": "`",     "97": "a",     "98": "b",     "99": "c",
"100": "d",
"101": "e",    "102": "f",    "103": "g",    "104": "h",
"105": "i",
"106": "j",    "107": "k",    "108": "l",    "109": "m",
"110": "n",
"111": "o",    "112": "p",    "113": "q",    "114": "r",
"115": "s",
"116": "t",    "117": "u",    "118": "v",    "119": "w",
"120": "x",
"121": "y",    "122": "z",    "123": "{",    "124": "|",
"125": "}",
"126": "~",    "127": ""
}

something like this from

```
String.fromCharCode(97) //will return 'a'
```

to

```
String.fromCharCode(122) //will return 'z'
```

if it starts with letter you compare next until it is not letter

Comment: Are you sure you got the OP's point? To automatically parse the relevant info out of the regex strings?

Comment: In Java, there is no `String.fromCharCode(97)`.